# How can I convert multi-line Python code to a single line?

Tags: python, autopep8

I have some code like:

```
imgs, original_img, original_size = load_img(INPUT_IMG_FILE,
                                             input_size=NETWORK_INPUT_SIZE,
                                             preprocess_fn=resnet.preprocess_input)
```

It has the extra spaces and indentation. I want to somehow convert it to one line.

I tried `autopep8.fix_code(code)`, but that keeps it as is.

I'd also like this code to be on one line:

```
      install_requires=['numpy>=1.9.1',
                        'scipy>=0.14',
                        'six>=1.9.0',
                        'pyyaml',
                        'h5py',
                        'keras_applications>=1.0.6',
                        'keras_preprocessing>=1.0.5'],
```

Comment: Considering how absurdly long the resulting line would be, it's no surprise that code formatters are reluctant to do that. Seriously, it'd be 130 characters. Imagine asking a question about the resulting code on Stack Overflow and forcing everyone to use the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: That's fine for my purposes.

Comment: `imgs, original_img, original_size = load_img(INPUT_IMG_FILE, input_size=NETWORK_INPUT_SIZE, preprocess_fn=resnet.preprocess_input)` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But how can I convert that automatically? Either with regex or some `autopep8` config?

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136742/team-member-is-vehemently-against-code-formatting/136795#136795 shows why exactly aggressively reformatting code like this is a very bad idea.

Comment: I'm not using it for anything that developers will ever see. The purpose is for a deep network training model

Comment: @Shamoon then you might get more meaningful results if working with the parse tree aka `ast` rather than raw text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `max_line_length` option:

```
autopep8.fix_code(code, options={'max_line_length': 150})
```

Another option is to ignore warnings about line length:

```
autopep8.fix_code(code, options={'ignore': ['E501']})
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify unlimited?

Comment: Yes, I just added a snippet for that

Comment: That didn't seem to reformat it. I added another code snippet as an example

Comment: Looks like the `aggressive` option has to also be passed (https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues/393#issuecomment-493337085)

Comment: `aggressive` set to 2 also seemed to do nothing